# How to prepare data into a LibSVM format from DataFrame?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, libsvm, apache-spark-ml

I want to make libsvm format, so I made dataframe to the desired format, but I do not know how to convert to libsvm format. The format is as shown in the figure. I hope that the desired libsvm type is **user item:rating** . If you know what to do in the current situation :

```scala
val ratings = sc.textFile(new File("/user/ubuntu/kang/0829/rawRatings.csv").toString).map { line =>
     val fields = line.split(",")
      (fields(0).toInt,fields(1).toInt,fields(2).toDouble)
}
val user = ratings.map{ case (user,product,rate) => (user,(product.toInt,rate.toDouble))}
val usergroup = user.groupByKey 

val data =usergroup.map{ case(x,iter) => (x,iter.map(_._1).toArray,iter.map(_._2).toArray)}

val data_DF = data.toDF("user","item","rating")
```

[image: DATAFRAME FIGURE]

I am using Spark 2.0.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The issue you are facing can be divided into the following :

- Converting your ratings (I believe) into `LabeledPoint` data *X*.
- Saving X in *libsvm* format.

**1. Converting your ratings into `LabeledPoint` data *X***

Let's consider the following raw ratings :

```
val rawRatings: Seq[String] = Seq("0,1,1.0", "0,3,3.0", "1,1,1.0", "1,2,0.0", "1,3,3.0", "3,3,4.0", "10,3,4.5")
```

You can handle those raw ratings as a [coordinate list matrix (COO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Coordinate_list_.28COO.29).

Spark implements a distributed matrix backed by an RDD of its entries : `CoordinateMatrix` where each entry is a tuple of (i: Long, j: Long, value: Double).

***Note : A CoordinateMatrix should be used only when both dimensions of the matrix are huge and the matrix is very sparse.*** (which is usually the case of user/item ratings.)

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.{CoordinateMatrix, MatrixEntry}
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

val data: RDD[MatrixEntry] = 
      sc.parallelize(rawRatings).map {
            line => {
                  val fields = line.split(",")
                  val i = fields(0).toLong
                  val j = fields(1).toLong
                  val value = fields(2).toDouble
                  MatrixEntry(i, j, value)
            }
      }
```

Now let's convert that `RDD[MatrixEntry]` to a `CoordinateMatrix` and extract the indexed rows :

```
val df = new CoordinateMatrix(data) // Convert the RDD to a CoordinateMatrix
                .toIndexedRowMatrix().rows // Extract indexed rows
                .toDF("label", "features") // Convert rows
```

**2. Saving LabeledPoint data in *libsvm* format**

Since **Spark 2.0**, You can do that using the `DataFrameWriter` . Let's create a small example with some dummy LabeledPoint data (you can also use the `DataFrame` we created earlier) :

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint
val pos = LabeledPoint(1.0, Vectors.dense(1.0, 0.0, 3.0))
val neg = LabeledPoint(0.0, Vectors.sparse(3, Array(0, 2), Array(1.0, 3.0)))

val df = Seq(neg,pos).toDF("label","features")
```

Unfortunately we still can't use the `DataFrameWriter` directly because while most pipeline components support backward compatibility for loading, some existing DataFrames and pipelines in Spark versions prior to 2.0, that contain vector or matrix columns, may need to be migrated to the new spark.ml vector and matrix types.

Utilities for converting DataFrame columns from `mllib.linalg` to `ml.linalg` types (and vice versa) can be found in `org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils.` In our case we need to do the following (for both the dummy data and the `DataFrame` from `step 1.`)

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils
// convert DataFrame columns
val convertedVecDF = MLUtils.convertVectorColumnsToML(df)
```

Now let's save the DataFrame :

```
convertedVecDF.write.format("libsvm").save("data/foo")
```

And we can check the files contents :

```
$ cat data/foo/part*
0.0 1:1.0 3:3.0
1.0 1:1.0 2:0.0 3:3.0
```

**EDIT**:
In current version of spark (2.1.0) there is no need to use `mllib` package. You can simply save `LabeledPoint` data in *libsvm* format like below:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.LabeledPoint
val pos = LabeledPoint(1.0, Vectors.dense(1.0, 0.0, 3.0))
val neg = LabeledPoint(0.0, Vectors.sparse(3, Array(0, 2), Array(1.0, 3.0)))

val df = Seq(neg,pos).toDF("label","features")
df.write.format("libsvm").save("data/foo")
```

Comment: Hi eliasah, I've tried your example under Spark 2.2.0, however it throws exception "java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: numFeatures". How did you solve it? Thanks.

Comment: But you can't really apply that to a large dataset can you?  Since you can't just map a current dataframe to a labeledPoint

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment @big_mike_boiii

Comment: Ok you are hard coding the values for pos and neg. suppose you have a Dataset or DataFrame with 10,000,000 rows though, how would you avoid the MLlib then?

Comment: @big_mike_boiii That was an example to illustrate my point. It all goes back to the idea of having a vector column and a label column. So whether you have 10 points or 10M, my answer remains the same.

Comment: Yeah but is there a way to make a DataFrame of LabeledPoints from a DataFrame of just Rows. Spark doesn’t allow to use a map on DataFrame.

Comment: @big_mike_boiii You can use Dataset then or you can always pull back to rdd if you are stuck map and then convert to DF

Comment: I don’t think you can use Dataset so easily.  And I was trying to avoid using RDD altogether.  Right now I’m only able to to use the Dataset if I map every field with a .asInstanceOf[Double] which is a bit of a hack.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189392/discussion-between-eliasah-and-big-mike-boiii).

Comment: please ,can you explain how to make pos, neg for 20m movielens.

Comment: @Salmaz I'm not sure I understand your question

Comment: How to make label column for large dataset like ratings in 20M movielens.

Answer (score 1):

In order to convert an existing to a typed `DataSet` I suggest the following; Use the following case class:

```
case class LibSvmEntry (
   value: Double,
   features: L.Vector)
```

The you can use the `map` function to convert it to a LibSVM entry like so:

`df.map[LibSvmEntry](r: Row => /* Do your stuff here*/)`

Answer (score 0):

libsvm datatype features  is a sparse vector, u can use pyspark.ml.linalg.SparseVector to solve the problem

```
a = SparseVector(4, [1, 3], [3.0, 4.0])

def sparsevecfuc(len,index,score):
    """
     args: len int, index array, score array
    """
    return SparseVector(len,index,score)
trans_sparse = udf(sparsevecfuc,VectorUDT())
```